# radio button postback event not working with bootstrap, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with an ASP.net, C# website. The postback event of a radio button and checkbox is not working.

How can we fix this, or how we can remove CSS or JQuery from the radio button or checkbox.

---

**Code**

```
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn1" runat="server" Text="Check me" 
        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="radio_checked"/> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" Text="radio button" 
        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_checked" />
```

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: hello Nicolai, thanks for reply. code i have used ' <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn1" runat="server" Text="Check me" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="radio_checked"/>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" Text="radio button" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_checked" />'

Comment: It works ok, so I think the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Javascript adds labels around the radio button/checkbox controls, which capture the click.  The control's AutoPostBack onclick never gets called.  To fix the issue, set the onclick of the label to be the same as the onclick of the control.

```
// Fix AutoPostBack issue due to Bootstrap Javascript
protected void RadioButton_FixAutoPostBack_OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
    HtmlGenericControl label = (HtmlGenericControl)radioButton.Parent;

    // Set onclick handler of the parent label to be the same as the radio button.
    //   This fixes issues caused by bootstrap javascript which adds labels.
    label.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
        "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\\'" + 
        radioButton.UniqueID + "\\',\\'\\')', 0)");
}
```

ASPX:

```
<label class="btn btn-yes" runat="server" id="LabelFoo">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButtonFoo" runat="server"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnPreRender="RadioButton_FixAutoPostBack_OnPreRender"
        OnCheckedChanged="RadioButtonFoo_CheckedChanged" />
</label>
```

Comment: I know this is an older question but I recently ran into this and it helped. FYI - this solution works with Bootstrap 4.x as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap then this problem comes coz bootstrap change all checkbox's and radio button's style and display those inside a `DIV` to change the look of checkbox and radio. AND `AutoPostBack` works on click event but the click event goes to `DIV`.

So the solution is to use the `on checked change` event. And the best way is to use `jQuery`.

add a script on top like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#idOfCheckbox").on('ifToggled', function (event) {
            __doPostBack('idOfCheckbox','');
        });
        $("#idOfRadio").on('ifToggled', function (event) {
            __doPostBack('idOfRadio','');
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can call it a secondary/alternate method to set `AutoPostBack=true`, which works for all input.